# lambda function not working properly in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I write lambda function on AWS, my test input is an array JSON, I wanted to pass each element of the array to a rest API.my code looks like :

```js
exports.handler = async(event) => {
    var index = 0
    var values = event.values;

    for (index = 0; index < values.length; ++index) {
        
               await callWebService(values)                    

    }
};


async function callWebService(values) {
console.log(values)
    var request = require('request');
   var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': http://test.com,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
        },
        body: "test"
    };
    request(options, function(error, response) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
                console.log(options);
        console.log(response.body);
    });
}
```

some time it runs for all element but usually just run for one of the element and console.log one of the response.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you are getting an exception every now and then and you are not catching them inside the loop so it ejects.

See if this logs anything. I've also taken the liberty to use `promisify` in the answer to modernize the code a bit. You can ignore that part (I didn't actually try it so I may be off a bit). The most important part to help debug your problem is really the `try/catch` I think.

```js
const util = require('util');
const request = util.promisify(require('request'));

exports.handler = async(event) => {
    var index = 0
    var values = event.values;

    for (index = 0; index < values.length; ++index) {
        try {
            await callWebService(values)                    
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
};


async function callWebService(values) {
   console.log(values)
   
   var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'url': http://test.com,
        'headers': {
            'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
        },
        body: "test"
    };

    const response = await request(options);
    console.log(response.body);
}
```